# Angular - Can't resolve all parameters for NgZone

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I'm learning Angular and currently trying to use the Firebase Authentication services. But I'm running into this error everytime I load the component that uses the service.

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgZone: (?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.mjs:11501:15)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.mjs:11491:16)
    at providerToFactory (core.mjs:11534:52)
    at providerToRecord (core.mjs:11521:25)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (core.mjs:11424:24)
    at core.mjs:11410:56
    at core.mjs:4167:76
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.mjs:4167:11)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.mjs:11410:13)
```

I inject it via to component like:

```
constructor(private operationService: OperationService, 
    private suscripctionService: SuscriptionService,
    private fb: FormBuilder, private firebaseService: FirebaseService)
```

My FirebaseService is annotated with Injectable, and I import the services I need.

```
import { Injectable, Inject, forwardRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { UserFirebase } from '../_models/UserFirebase';
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
export class FirebaseService {
  userData: any;

  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
    ) {}
```

And in app.module.ts, in my providers array:

```
providers: [ AngularFireAuth, AngularFirestore, NgZone, FirebaseService ]
```

I know there are serveral questions like this asked, sadly I've not been able to solve my problem. I'm afraid this might be a circular dependency I'm missing.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to add NgZone to providers in app.module.ts ? Angular does it internally for you.

Comment: I removed it, and end up with the following:

`NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FirebaseService -> AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FirebaseService -> AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:`

Comment: Fixed that already, wasn't initializing. Thanks! I didn't need to add it!